# Sync failure between Gerrit & Github for Windows client

Tags: ssh, git, github, gerrit

I've set up a POC Gerrit server, and am able to push to it via the Git Command Line.  I'm trying to set it up so that less experienced colleagues can use the Github for Windows client to sync commits with Gerrit but the sync always fails.  I notice that when I use GfW it creates a github ssh key so I've tried changing the config file:

```
Host gerrit
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.user
```

and I have the remote set up in GfW as:

```
ssh://user@gerrit:29418/gerrit-test HEAD:refs/for/master
```

I am able to sync the GfW client with a separate remote Git server I have set up, so I don't think it's necessarily either GfW or Gerrit on their own that's the problem, more the combination of the two.  Any ideas what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have two keys. You need to have each public key installed on the Gerrit instance for the user.